# What does ?. and ?? mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

**Here in below code what does ?. and ?? mean**

```
history.replace(loacation.state?.redirectPath ?? '/home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Optional chaining (?.)**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) said that

> The optional chaining operator (?.) permits reading the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is
> valid.

> **The ?. operator functions similarly to the . chaining operator, except
> that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or
> undefined)**, the expression short-circuits with a return value of
> undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the
> given function does not exist.

```js
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

console.log(adventurer.dog?.name); // expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.dog.name); // Thow an error message like 
//`"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",`
```

**2. Nullish coalescing operator (??)**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) said that

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that
> returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is
> null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
const foo = null ?? 'default string';
console.log(foo);
// expected output: "default string"
```

**==>** So in case of `loacation.state?.redirectPath` is `null or undefined`, then value will be `'/home'`